# Build Ubuntu Touch: adding android system image to installation ... error: device not found

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, compiling

I'm trying to build Ubuntu touch from source. I'm building it for nexus 4 (mako) I've alredy install ubuntu on it, but a want to play with the source code so I need to build it.

Everything seems to work fine except for this  :

```
$ ./rootstock-touch-install wily-preinstalled-touch-armhf.tar.gz /out/target/product/mako/system.img
transfering rootfs tarball ... [done]
preparing system-image on device ... [done]
unpacking rootfs tarball to system-image ... [done]
adding android system image to installation ... error: device not found
```

Is there a way to get to the logs to find the issue?